# When doing an ActiveRecord query, how do I prioritize a record that has an attribute marked as true first then created_at desc after?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a bunch of `Answers` on a `Question`.

What I want to do is order the answers on each question in two steps:

1. If there is an accepted answer, return that one first, THEN...
2. Return the rest of the answers, `created_at: :desc`

If #1 doesn't exist, just default to 2.

This is what I tried, but it didn't work:

```
[21] pry(main)> q.answers.order(:accepted, created_at: :desc)
[23] pry(main)> q.answers.order(accepted: true, created_at: :asc).inspect
ArgumentError: Direction "true" is invalid. Valid directions are: [:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"]
from /gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1164:in `block (2 levels) in validate_order_args'
[24] pry(main)> q.answers.order(accepted: "true", created_at: :asc).inspect
ArgumentError: Direction "true" is invalid. Valid directions are: [:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"]
from gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1164:in `block (2 levels) in validate_order_args'
```

How do I achieve this?

**Edit 1**

This is an example of an answer with an `accepted: true`:

```
[26] pry(main)> q.answers.first
=> #<Answer:0x007f997d7a5a80
 id: 69,
 body:
  "public static Process CreateProcessAsUser(string filename, string args)\r\n {\r\n     var hToken = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token;\r\n     var hDupedToken = IntPtr.Zero;\r\n\r\n     var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();\r\n     var sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();\r\n     sa.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);\r\n\r\n     try\r\n     {\r\n         if (!DuplicateTokenEx(\r\n                 hToken,\r\n                 GENERIC_ALL_ACCESS,\r\n                 ref sa,\r\n                 (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification,\r\n                 (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,\r\n                 ref hDupedToken\r\n             ))\r\n             throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());\r\n\r\n         var si = new STARTUPINFO();\r\n         si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);\r\n         ",
 user_id: 1547,
 question_id: 47,
 created_at: Wed, 15 Jun 2016 05:20:11 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Mon, 20 Jun 2016 22:34:08 UTC +00:00,
 accepted: true,
 language: nil,
 comments_count: nil>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass a string to the `order` method:

```
q.answers.order("accepted = true DESC").order(:created_at)
```

Comment: Perfect dude! Just what I was looking for. Thanks!